# Out of memory error for convolution using Theano

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, theano, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am doing a convolution in Theano:

```
theano.tensor.nnet.conv.conv2d(x,h, border_mode='full')
```

and it runs out of memory, I get the following message:

```
RuntimeError: GpuCorrMM failed to allocate working memory of 3591 x 319086

Apply node that caused the error: GpuCorrMM_gradInputs{valid, (1, 1)}(GpuContiguous.0, GpuContiguous.0)
Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, (True, False, True, False)), CudaNdarrayType(float32, (False, True, False, False))]
Inputs shapes: [(1, 513, 1, 7), (1, 1, 513, 622)]
Inputs strides: [(0, 7, 0, 1), (0, 0, 622, 1)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
```

I have tried setting theano flags to 'optimizer_excluding=conv_dnn', but still didn't work. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to allocate a matrix which need something like 9TB of memory. An individual neuron needs 2.5GB of memory. The only optimization I know for such issues is to either decrease the number of units or buying more RAM. Loads of RAM :)

Comment: Well. Or just plain old dimension reduction or downsampling ;)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I disabled g++ during runtime by simply remove the (MinGW) bin directory from the path variable. The processing time is slow, but it completes process.

My program execution enviroment: OS Windows Vista 32 bit, CPU Intel 2.16 GHz, RAM 4.00 GB and no GPU